# Nodejs Syntax error unexpected token JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, syntax

I'm trying to get data from keepa API for my app.

The status code of my request is 200 but I'm getting the Syntax error unexpected token JSON at position 0 for every request.

```
response.on("data", function(data){
const asinData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(asinData);
res.send();
});
```

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(data)`, does it pass an object, value or nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Can you print this "data"? Guess there is an error in it. I think "data" is a "serverResponse" object and "serverResponse.data" is what you want to see there, try to console.log it.

Comment: Please attach this "data" here, we need to see either code or a screenshot of console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Is the response object coming from the *http* core module *get()* method? If so this may be helpful: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback.

Basically, the response object you are getting is an *http.IncomingMessage* instance, which is a readable stream. The *data* event is triggered on this object not when the response body has been fully received, but every time a small part - a chunk - of it has. You would need to aggregate all of these chunks into a single piece of data before attempting to parse it into a javascript object.

Also, be aware the chunks are emitted as buffers by default - not as strings. You can set the stream to emit strings instead by setting the stream encoding before starting to read the chunks.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I'm using the HTTP core module... I just re-corded exactly by the instructions in the link, and still - I'm getting the same error